# Code won't run because I can't output more than one variable in document.write

Tags: javascript

My code won't run when I try to display more than one variable in the `document.write` section of the code.  I'm pretty sure I was doing everything right.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var name = prompt("Welcome to the Fruity Store. What is your name?","");
var product = prompt("What is the name of the product you would like?","");
var price = 1*prompt("How much does it cost?","");
var quantity = 1*prompt("How many of the fruit would you like?","");
var discount = 1*prompt("What was the discount of the product in decimal form?","");
var costoforder = (price*quantity);
var discounted = (price*quantity*discount);
var totalorder = (costoforder - discounted);

document.write("Thank you for placing an order with us " +name ) 
document.write("<p>The cost of buying " +quantity "of " +product "is " +costoforder    </p>)
document.write("<p>The discount for this purchase is " +discounted </p>)
document.write("<p>With discount, your total order cost is " +totalorder</p>)

</script>
```

Comment: Missing a bunch of `+` in `:buying " +quantity "of " +product "is " +costoforder...` each of the vars should be followed by a `+` as in `buying " + quantity + "of " + product + "is " + costoforder + "..."`

Comment: "My code won't run". Have you tried debugging? What does the browser console say?

Comment: missing string concatenation `+`, seems you didnt checked your code thoroughly

Comment: debugger = stack overflow.  Getting an answer in 3 minutes is pretty cool.  But yes, you need to learn how to use Firebug or Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some plus signs in your string concatenation.

```
"<p>The cost of buying " + quantity + " of " + product + " is " + etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "+" signs after your variables.

You put

```
"String" + variable "string"
```

Instead of

```
"string" + variable + "string"
```

Several times in your document.write statements

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the plus sign, `+`, for string concatenation.  Also you are missing the ; after the statements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var name = prompt("Welcome to the Fruity Store. What is your name?","");
var product = prompt("What is the name of the product you would like?","");
var price = 1*prompt("How much does it cost?","");
var quantity = 1*prompt("How many of the fruit would you like?","");
var discount = 1*prompt("What was the discount of the product in decimal form?","");
var costoforder = (price*quantity);
var discounted = (price*quantity*discount);
var totalorder = (costoforder - discounted);

document.write("Thank you for placing an order with us " + name ); 
document.write("<p>The cost of buying " + quantity + "of " + product + "is " + costoforder   + "</p>");
document.write("<p>The discount for this purchase is " + discounted + "</p>");
document.write("<p>With discount, your total order cost is " +totalorder + "</p>");

</script>
```